# Property -webkit-border-radius is an unknown vendor extension

Tags: css, validation

When I validate css3 I got this error.

```
Property -webkit-border-radius is an unknown vendor extension
Property -moz-border-radius is an unknown vendor extension
Property -webkit-border-radius is an unknown vendor extension
```

How can I get 100% CSS3 valid?

```
-webkit-border-radius: 50%;
-moz-border-radius: 50%;
border-radius:50%;
```

Answer (score 0):

Removing the prefixed properties would make it 100% valid but reduce compatibility with older versions of the browsers they target - considering that these properties have been supported for quite a while now it's probably not a huge loss in browser support so you can likely remove them with minimal impact.

Comment: So in short you probably only need `border-radius:50%;` not the other 2 rules :)